# Does AWS Batch charge you when no jobs are running?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-batch

I have setup AWS Batch compute environment. Mostly jobs will run on daily or weekly basis.

My question is when there is no jobs are running on ec2 compute environment, am i charged for it.

How AWS Batch is managing compute environment? After successful ran of my job AWS will terminate EC2 compute environment? and then recreate it when my job needs to be run.

AWS batch will charge based on EC2 pricing (it uses EC2 in  backend).

Answer (score 1):

The [AWS Batch pricing page](https://aws.amazon.com/batch/pricing/) states:

> There is no additional charge for AWS Batch. You pay for AWS resources
>   (e.g. EC2 instances or AWS Lambda functions) you create to store and
>   run your application. You only pay for what you use, as you use it;
>   there are no minimum fees and no upfront commitments.

The [AWS Batch FAQ](https://aws.amazon.com/batch/faqs/) states:

> When capacity is no longer needed, AWS Batch will remove it.

So, you are charged for compute (ECS,  EC2, Lambda) only when your jobs are running. You're also paying for persistent storage (to store your code, for example) whether or not jobs are running. Storage prices are low, however, so that's barely noticeable.

Comment: Thanks, I got it. When i watch the EC2 console, I can see the EC2 instances running which is created by AWS Batch.